# How to run a program before answer a call in android?

Tags: android, security, android-2.2-froyo

I want to write a program in android will ask for a password when an incoming call is detected.  The program will only allow the call to be answered if the password is correct.

How should I implement that?

For example, I found a program that does this:    [App Lock](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cc.applock&feature=search_result)

...but I have no idea where I should start. Should I write a service?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta for security.if some body call you , just you should see the name and answer it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android incoming call screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486547/android-incoming-call-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you: https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html

You have to register a broadcast receiver in order to catch the events (call ringing, etc, etc..) and based on the various states, you can perform any operations you may want.

Also check this link: [How to block calls in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android)