# How to run an application before any other application in android?

Tags: android

I want to write a program in that if somebody wants to open a application (like Contacts Application) , first my program starts and user enter a password and if password is correct , let contacts program to open.

i know it s possible because [App Lock](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cc.applock&feature=search_result) program does it.

should i run a service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a program before answer a call in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219061/how-to-run-a-program-before-answer-a-call-in-android)

Comment: @jeffamaphone i think there is difference between them.
in that case you can use Telephony state.but her?

Comment: It it possible, but it exploits security loopholes and is not supported.

Comment: @CommonsWare absolutely it is possible but it supported too!because up application use it!

Comment: No, it is not supported. Just because developers use unsupported techniques does not somehow make them magically supported.

Comment: can you specify the security loop hole ? i might write an article to the security magazine here :-) 
10x.